# CMake: running a program while installing

Tags: c, installation, cmake, include

I need to run a `sed` (or equivalent) command while performing a

```
install(FILES t/a/a.h t/b/b.h ... DESTINATION include/t)
```

in order to filter `#include <t/a/a.h>` -> `#include <t/a.h>`.

How should I specify the relevant command in CMakeLists.txt?

Reason why I need this is I have an externally maintained library I need to import in my code.

This library (actually a piece of [ccan](https://github.com/rustyrussell/ccan), if it matters)  is structured like:

```
ccan
├── block_pool
│   ├── block_pool.c
│   ├── block_pool.h
│   ├── _info
│   ├── LICENSE -> ../../licenses/BSD-MIT
│   └── test
│       └── run.c
├── build_assert
│   ├── build_assert.h
│   ├── _info
│   ├── LICENSE -> ../../licenses/CC0
...
├── check_type
│   ├── check_type.h
...
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── compiler
│   ├── compiler.h
...
├── container_of
...
```

each `ccan/xxx/xxx.h` may have constructs like:

```
...
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ccan/str/str.h>
#include <ccan/container_of/container_of.h>
#include <ccan/check_type/check_type.h>
...
```

and I would like to "compress" the dir tree to a simpler:

```
#include <ccan/str.h>
#include <ccan/container_of.h>
#include <ccan/check_type.h>
```

Alternatively, if the above is too complex,  what is the right spell
to copy the include directory as-is? Should I add an `install(FILES...)`
for each file?

Comment: You can do `install(CODE "execute_process(...)")` but I wouldn't recommend doing this at all. People may be familiar with the normal include structure of ccan and have those kinds of includes in the code using your lib which would not work with the way you restructure the include dir. Is it even necessary to add those includes to your public headers? If it isn't, but you're using the headers internally only, you need not install the headers at all...

Comment: Note: `install(CODE)` runs during the `cmake --install ...` which is also executed during the preparation of packages when using `cpack`. There are ways of integrating scripts running during the installation of certain package types, if that's what you're looking for, but I'd recommend any adjustments to be done before packaging instead (which `install(CODE)` does), since this allows `cmake --install` to work and also works with package types not providing the functionality of running a script during installation such as `.tar.gz`